# Angle between camera and object planes

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, homography

I have a task to calculate the angle between object and camera planes.
As an input I have src and dst points(I choose src on the photo, dst are constants), so with cv2 I compute a homography matrix.

```
homography_matrix, _ = cv2.findHomography(dst_points, src_points)
```

How can I then receive an angle from this transformation matrix?

I tried different formulas and instruments in cv2. But nothing works.

Comment: this probably involves decomposing the homography. it may require having an estimate of the camera matrix.

Comment: cv2.solvePnp, if src and dst points are, what I guess them to be.